# Django protocol relative URLs when serving static files

Tags: django

When ever I add a add a static file using the `{% static '...' %}` tag the URL output is an absolute url rather than a protocol relative URL. How do I get protocol relative URLs in Django? Do I have to hard code it in?

I get this using the static tag:
`<script src="http://s.cdn.example.com/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>` where I want `<script src="//s.cdn.example.com/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: What is your `STATIC_URL` set to?

Comment: @HeddevanderHeide Ahh right stupid me. I set the `STATIC_URL` to the protocol relative URL now and it works. It had the protocol before. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `STATIC_URL` when using a subdomain to serve your static files to the protocol relative url like so `STATIC_URL = '//s.cdn.example.com/'`.